# GCD of a Huge Number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I want to know that how can we find the GCD of two positive huge numbers $A$ and $B$. If we know $n$ numbers whose product is $A$ and similarly $m$ numbers whose product is $B$.

Example: Let $A$ be $30$ and $B$ be $15$, and we are given $3$ numbers for $A$ $2$,$5$ and $3$  (product of $2$ ,$5$ and $3$ is $30$ which is $A$) and $2$ numbers for $B$ i.e $5$ and $3$.(product of $5$ and $3$ is $15$ which is $B$).

We basically have to find $\gcd(2\times 5\times 3,5\times 3)$.
Here we can multiply as $A$ and $B$ are small to get the GCD but in general $A$ and $B$ are huge.

Here is the problem statement [link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/HG/)

Comment: Euclid's Algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: How we can use Euclid if our number is in product form i.e gcd(a*b*c,d*e*f)  not in simple form by simple i mean gcd(A,B) .Can you Elaborate ?

Comment: @AyushMishra I explained this in my post - if the number is not in prime factorisation you have to make a factor tree to find the prime factors of the factors of your number.

Comment: @AyushMishra You can just multiply them out and then proceed from there; unless the number is already prime factorized or nearly so this is probably the best thing to do.

Comment: @Ian Breaking the number's factors (which I assume the OP already has) into the prime factorisation is by far the easiest method. Why would you want to overcomplicate this?

Comment: @TobyMak "unless the number is already prime factorized or nearly so". If it is then sure the prime factorization technique is fine. But if the given factors themselves are difficult to prime factorize (as is usually the case if the factors themselves are large) then it is not worthwhile to try.

Comment: I'll clarify with the OP first - @AyushMishra are the numbers already factorised into other factors?

Comment: I have made Edit to my Post and added the problem link to make it more clear. No the number is not prime factorized..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative method to find the GCD is to compare each prime factor, such as $(2,3,5,7 \cdots)$, and compare which exponent has the smallest index.
We can then multiply the smallest prime factors together to get the result of the GCD. The two prime factorisations should include the same primes so that each prime has a pair to correspond to in the other list.

This works because for 3 numbers which have $3^p, 3^q, 3^r$ as their indices (respectively), since in a prime factorisation $p, q,r$ are integers, if $p$ is the smallest in the group then $3^{q-p}$, and $3^{r-p}$ are also integers, so they are all multiples of $3^p$. This can be generalised easily to a group of $n$ numbers.

For example, to find the GCD of $(198, 616)$, knowing that $198 = 2*3^2*11$, and $616 = 2^3*7*11$, then:

$$2^\color{blue}1*3^2*7^\color{blue}0*11^\color{blue}1$$
$$2^3*3^\color{blue}0*7^1*11^\color{blue}1$$.

Therefore the GCD of $(198, 616)$ is $2^1 * 3^0 * 7^0 * 11^1$, or $2*1*1*11$ which is $22$.

With a prime factorisation for each number, the process becomes much easier, because we can compare each exponent directly instead of using an abstract method of quotients and remainders. However, the only problem is to factorise the given factors into primes, which can be a struggle, especially when that number can be prime or have few divisors.

Comment: This is very slow unless the factorization is already given.

Comment: @Ian This is precisely what the OP wants - a method using factors, or prime factors to find the GCD. He is asking what the fastest method to find the GCD is with a prime factorisation.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what "in product form" necessarily means, but if so then sure this is a good answer. But I suspect the given numbers are in general not prime.

Comment: Yes I agree with @ian this will be quite slow .As the number A can be written as a Product of n number where n can be upto 1000 and each of the term in product can be Upto 10^9.

Comment: I agree with @ian now after seeing the original problem - factorising the factors is going to take some time using trial and improvement, and there are many possibilities to break the number into different numbers of factors. For example, you can have 2 factors or 20 for the same number.

Comment: So any better approach you can suggest @TobyMak.

Comment: In this case, I believe the Euclidean algorithm is the best solution (that I know of).

Comment: How as i mentioned earlier number is in this form gcd (a*b*c..,d*e*f...) not in gcd(A,B) ..Is there any property of gcd in product form which i don't Know @TobyMak..How to apply Euclid in product form ?

Comment: You could find simple common factors such as $2, 3, 5, 9, 10$ and so on, to divide them by one of these common factors if possible. This will help eliminate $1$ or $2$ steps from the Euclidean algorithm (which is already quite fast).

Comment: @AyushMishra Have you actually tried just multiplying $A$ and $B$ out and using the Euclidean algorithm? It should not be a problem on the number scales you suggested in your comment (up to $1000$ factors each up to $10^9$) provided that you use bignum arithmetic.

Comment: it is not possible as suppose A = 10^900 then we can have 100 factor and each equal to 10^9..@Ian

Comment: @AyushMishra It is totally feasible to run the Euclidean algorithm on two numbers on the order of $10^{9000}$ on a modern CPU.